# Multiple players via game center for iOS 7

Tags: ios7, game-center, multipeer-connectivity

Seems like Game center promised this feature to let multiple players play the same game at real time.

By researching a bit, just found http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22,  but I would not use the GKSession to find out each others.

Then go to http://www1.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/people/98-teaching/tutorials/508-sgd-ws13-tutorial-multiplayer-games , seems like more sensible for iOS 7 without GKSession.

Just want to get a quick test with some sample support multiple players, even in the same Wifi, or just Bluetooth by using multiple peer to peer in iOS 7.

Question here to get the simple sample or any specific clues for this. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You have a new framework dedicated to peer connections in iOS7 called `MultipeerConnectivity`. You can find an exemple on the main's developer website [here](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html).

There is also a video at the WWDC 2013 introducing it : [Nearby Networking with Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

Comment: Just wonder the difference between GameKit and Multipeer connectivity ? Just a simple question before digging into these. thanks !

Comment: The MultipeerConnectivity frameworks allow you to create an application without making it a game. With MultipeerConnectivity you simply create connection between devices. Gamekit is dedicated to create multiplayer games on the Game Center platform.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the guide by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW19

It has all the information, and is accurate. Works with iOS 7.

I don't use GKSession for anything -> All the information I need is available in the GKMatch object.